# Regex: Detect the presence of overlapping or non-overlapping repeating patterns of a given length

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Is this possible to do with regex?

For example, in: "tagaga", I'd like to match "aga" because it occurs more than once.

```
'(.{3})(.*)\1'
```

finds non-overlapping matches (matches "agacaga" in "tagacaga") but not overlapping matches.

However, using look-ahead in this way does not work for me:

```
'(.{3})(.*)(?=\1)'
```

Alternatively, if the regex solution doesn't exist, is there a dynamic programming solution for this?

Ultimately, I only care about presence and do not need the matched string. I am working in MATLAB, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Test string:

```
tagaga
```

Regex:

```
(?=(aga)).{2}(?<=.)(\1)
```

Matches:

```
"aga", "aga"
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/uT5fS1

However depending on the length if the match, ie. in your example `aga` length is 3, so you would have to modify  the quantifier to the length -1. (in this case `{2}`).  So..  If your match was `abca` you would have to change the quantifier to `{3}`.

So with test example:

```
abcabca
```

Regex:

```
(?=(abca)).{3}(?<=.)(\1)
```

Matches:

```
"abca", "abca"
```

Comment: (?=(.{3})).+(\1) seems to work fine for my purposes in the tester. None of the answers work with MATLAB though. I realized that MATLAB simply cannot capture characters as a token without removing them from the string [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848759/match-overlapping-patterns-with-capture-using-a-matlab-regular-expression). I will have to look into other options beyond Regex. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Move lookahead part to the middle:

```
(.+?)(?=(.+?))\1\2
```

Example in Javascript:

```js
/(.+?)(?=(.+?))\1\2/.test('asdf')     // false
/(.+?)(?=(.+?))\1\2/.test('tagaga')   // true
/(.+?)(?=(.+?))\1\2/.test('tagacaga') // false
/(.+?)(?=(.+?))\1\2/.test('agag')     // false
```

Comment: However I think your regex is actually only matching consecutive `ag`. Test example `agag` would return `true`. It's not overlapping.